# Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlRowType' and 'bool'?8

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have to bind drop down list inside a grid view. While using the given below code showing one error. Help me to find a proper solution. Thank you.

Code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow && GridView1.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex)
    {
        DropDownList DropdownList1 = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropdownList1");
        ShadingAnalysisDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_AutoAssignCadTeamTableAdapter at;
        at = new ShadingAnalysisDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_AutoAssignCadTeamTableAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt=at.GetUpdateTeam();
        DropdownList1.DataSource = dt;
        DropdownList1.DataTextField = "Assigned_Team";
        DropdownList1.DataValueField = "Assigned_Team";
        DropdownList1.DataBind();
        DropdownList1.Items.FindByValue((e.Row.FindControl("Label1") as Label).Text).Selected = true;
    }
}
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateEditButton="True" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="State" HeaderText="State" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="State" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="District" HeaderText="District" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="District" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Site_ID" HeaderText="Site ID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Site_ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Site_Name" HeaderText="Site Name" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Site_Name" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Team" SortExpression="Assigned_Team">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Width="88px">
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Assigned_Team") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Created_Date" HeaderText="Created Date" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Created_Date" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Created_By" HeaderText="Created By" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Created_By" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: You are assigning `e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow` - you need double equals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in this way:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
        if (GridView1.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex)
        {     
        DropDownList DropdownList1 = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropdownList1");
        ShadingAnalysisDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_AutoAssignCadTeamTableAdapter at;
        at = new ShadingAnalysisDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_AutoAssignCadTeamTableAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt=at.GetUpdateTeam();
        DropdownList1.DataSource = dt;
        DropdownList1.DataTextField = "Assigned_Team";
        DropdownList1.DataValueField = "Assigned_Team";
        DropdownList1.DataBind();
        DropdownList1.Items.FindByValue((e.Row.FindControl("Label1") as Label).Text).Selected = true;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have a typo in your `if` statement.

```
if (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow && GridView1.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex)
```

Should be

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && GridView1.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex)
```

Notice you wrote your first equals as an assignment statement but it should be a conditional equals.